# Doubt regarding expression of a Definite Integral containing two variables.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, functions, definite-integrals

[The picture with the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBzbP.jpg)

I would also appreciate an explanation as to how to make sense of F(t) in this context, should it be treated as a variable and be integrated inside the integral or should it be interpreted as treating 'x' as a constant and then change it to 't'.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: you have an issue with variable scope. In particular, you have a definition of f(x) in terms of an integral of t. But then you consider f(t). If you could do that, you could consider f(t^2+1)or any other f(a function of t). That is, your x is a function of t, and so you wouldn't be able to pull it out of your integral dt as you did.

Comment: Your first option is correct. The integrals have been completed, they are now simply numbers. Now you are simply replacing the symbol n with the symbol t.